# DirectX, GDI+ or SDI on Windows XP?

Tags: directx, 2d, gdi+, directx-9

1. If I want to do scaling and compositing of 2D anti-aliased vector and bitmap images in real-time on Windows XP and later versions of Windows, making the best use of hardware acceleration available, should I be using GDI+ or DirectX 9.0c? (Actually, Windows XP and Windows 7 are important but we're not concerned about performance on Vista.)
2. Is there any merit in using SDL, given that the application is not cross-platform (and never will be)? I wonder if SDL might make it easier to switch to whichever underlying drawing API gives better performance…
3. Where can I find the documentation for doing scaling and compositing of 2D images in DirectX 9.0c? (I found the documentation for DirectDraw but read that it is deprecated after DirectX 7. But Direct2D is not available until DirectX 10.)
4. Can I reasonably expect scaling and compositing to be hardware accelerated on Windows XP on a mid- to low-spec PC (i.e. integrated graphics)? If not then does it even matter whether I use GDI+ or DirectX 9.0c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this: [2D Rendering in DirectX 8](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/directx-and-xna/2d-rendering-in-directx-8-r1434).

It appears that since Microsoft removed DirectDraw after DirectX 7 they expected all 2D drawing to be done using the 3D API. This would explain why I totally failed to find the documentation I was looking for.

The article looks promising so far.

Here's another: [2D Programming in a 3D World](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3062/2d_programming_in_a_3d_world.php)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use GDI+. It does everything in software, and it has a rendering model that is not good for performance in software. You'd be better off with just about anything else.

Direct3D or OpenGL (which you can access via SDL if you want a more complete API that is cross-platform) will give you the best performance on hardware that supports it. Direct2D is in the same boat but is not available on Windows XP. My understanding is that, at least in the case of Intel's integrated GPU's, the hardware is able to do simple operations like transforming and composing, and that most of the problems with these GPU's are with games that have high demands for features and performance, and are optimized for ATI/Nvidia cards. If you somehow find a machine where Direct3D is not supported by the video card and is falling back to software, then you might have a problem.

I believe SDL uses DirectDraw on Windows for its non-OpenGL drawing. Somehow I got the impression that DirectDraw does all its operations in software in modern releases of Windows (and given what DirectDraw is used for it never really mattered since the win9x era), but I'm not able to verify that.

The ideal would be a cross-platform vector graphics library that can make use of Direct3D or OpenGL for rendering, but AFAICT no such thing is available. The Cairo graphics library lacks acceleration on Windows, and Mozilla has started a project called Azure that apparently has that but doesn't appear to be designed for use outside of their projects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It sounds like I should definitely avoid SDI+ and DirectDraw. So does Direct3D have an API for 2D drawing - especially scaling and compositing? If so, where can I find the documentation? Everything I've read so far leaps straight into polygons, virtual cameras, and textures - none of which I think are relevant.

Comment: Wikipedia says DirectDraw _is_ hardware-accelerated. :S